# Phonegap - Open Link in Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

Before I updated my application to Cordova 2.5.0, my basic link opened up into Safari. Now it just loads in my Application view and not into Safari.

I had the following code:
 `Contact Us by visiting, <a href="http://site.com/contact.php">
                        our website! </a>`

Any idea on how I can fix this.

For more information: it all started when we switched to config.xml from Cordova/Phonegap.plist.

Comment: you used older version phonegap before update? phonegap used webview(webkit) and not able to use safari.

Comment: Yea, used to when you opened a link (with a http://), it would open in Safari. Like it would jump applications.

Answer (score 5):

1)open links in safari

paste the code in your MainViewController.m file

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *url = [request URL];

    // Intercept the external http requests and forward to Safari.app
    // Otherwise forward to the PhoneGap WebView
    if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"] || [[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"https"]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        return NO;
    }
    else {
        return [ super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType ];
    }
}
```

2)open links in InAppBrowser

```
function OpenLink()
                    {
                    alert(adlink); //adlink: http://www.google.com
                        var ref = window.open(adlink, '_blank', 'location=yes');//adlink is url
                        var myCallback = function() { alert(event.url); }
                        ref.addEventListener('loadstart', myCallback);
                        ref.removeEventListener('loadstart', myCallback);
                          }
```

Comment: This worked for me in the latest version of PhoneGap.  Nothing else worked for me in the iOS Simulator. +1

Comment: The particular app I'm building has an iframe on the page and this is opening it in safari as well. Is there a simple fix for this?

Answer (score 4):

1. Add target="_blank" to your links. 
   ie:

   ```
   <a href="http://www.brandonbrotsky.com/" target="_blank"></a>
   ```
2. Make sure access has an origin of * /> in your config.xml (make sure its the one in the root of the app directory, above the www folder.
   ie:

   ```
   <access origin="*" />
   ```
3. Add the following code to MainViewController.m

   ```
   - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
   {
       NSURL *url = [request URL];

       // Intercept the external http requests and forward to Safari.app
       // Otherwise forward to the PhoneGap WebView
       if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"] || [[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"https"]) {
           [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
           return NO;
       }
       else {
           return [ super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType ];
       }
   }
   ```

I made a quick video explaining how to fix this issue:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zqbjXSnAR-Q&feature=c4-overview&list=UUefS6KLvFQVjhmL6hiBq4Sg

Hope it helps!

Comment: a quick explanation or summary would be immensely appreciated on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I have been wrestling with this problem a lot lately and have come up with an answer that works for me at least. Cordova 2.6 and JQuery Mobile.

```
<a href="http://yoursite.something.com" target="_system"> the external link </a>
```

A fair amount of answers have you using target="_blank". But that just opens the link in their WebView. Hope this works for you like it did for me!

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I need to use the `onclick="window.open('http://example.com', '_system')"` to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this : window.open('http://google.com','_system');

Source is here : http://wiki.apache.org/cordova/InAppBrowser

Comment: In Phonegap 3.3, this opens within the app, not in the system browser. (Tested iOS6/7) (e.g. <a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://site.com/accounts/password_reset/','_system')">

Comment: This is because the InAppBrowser plugin needs to be installed first.